# Place an HTML element on one of 5 pages at random intervals? JavaScript, jQuery, MySQL, or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Let's say we have this html element:

`<img src="icon.png">`

And we have 5 pages on our website such as:

```
index.php
products.php
register.php
about.php
terms.php
```

What is a good approach to place the HTML element on one of the above pages randomly? It should only ever stay on 1 of these pages for a certain amount of time like 3 hours.

I haven't tried anything because I cannot figure out how this should be done... I've got a fair knowledge of coding in PHP, JS/jQuery and using MySQL so the language proficiency wouldn't be an issue. What do you think I can do?

Comment: use mysql event scheduler set it to run every three hours. randomly pick one of your pages, store it in the database. and query it when displaying.

Comment: Great idea... I still wonder if there's anything a little lighter on the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a table in your database to store which page the code block should be on, the time of expiration, and the code block itself.
2. On your php pages, check the database to see if the code block should be included or not.
3. When the time expires, you can set a new random page for the code block in your PHP code, or you can set up a cron job.

Also, although your question states "MySQL", you might want to look into using Redis, as it allows you to set an expiry time on key / values.

Comment: I used a very similar approach to this and it's successful. Thanks!